# mpiexec - Credentials for user rejected connecting host

Tags: windows, mpi4py, mpiexec

To do some exercise to be more familiar with MPI, i installed MS-MPI on my windows 10 machine, and then mpi4py (python MPI). I tried a hello_world code:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

def main ():
    comm = MPI. COMM_WORLD
    rank = comm . Get_rank ()
    size = comm . Get_size ()
    print " hello from " + str( rank ) + " in " + str( size )


if __name__ == " __main__ ":
    main ()
```

Then, with a windows command as admin i executed the following command:

```
mpiexec -n 8 python MPI_Test.py
```

I get:

> User credentials needed to launch processes: account (domain\user)
>   [DESKTOP-3CFSBJ8\Hazem]:

I did a registration, as mpiexec - register from username/pwd, then execute again that command, and i get the following error:

> Credentials for user rejected connecting to host.

THE PROBLEM COMES WHEN EXECUTING THE COMMAND mpiexec.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue, the solution is:

6. Type ”mpiexec -n 3 cpi.exe” to run the sample program. You will get a response like this:
   ”user credentials needed to launch process”
7. Type your Windows username and Windows password, the sample program will run.
8. In order not to enter credentials every time you run mpiexec, you can register your username
   and password by command ”mpiexec -register”

source: https://www.cmpe.boun.edu.tr/sites/default/files/mpi_install_tutorial.pdf

Comment: according to this page, the username should be avoided and only password is necessary: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-clusters-and-hpc-technology/topic/735462
This approach worked for me.